# quadrotor experimental identification

Tags: control, quadcopter, brushless-motor, uav

i want to model the quadrotor using experimental method "i have not built it yet" what i want to do is: turn only one motor at a specific speed ,then plot the x,y,z and the angles then identify the transfert functions from the plots,x/w1,y/w1,... and so on, but i don't know if it's possible or what graphs i will have,so if you know about the subject or maybe tried something like that, and feel free to add anything you think might be helpfull

Comment: Sounds like a defined input you could put into a dynamic model of your quadrotor.